# Calculate the weights needed for a barbell to get a specific weight

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to calculate the optimal set of plates to put on a barbell to get to the desired weight. It's working well, but the problem is it will always find the first possible weight **under** the target weight.

For example, if you want your barbell to weigh `29kg`, you can either put `27.5kg` or `30kg` given the set of plates below, where each plate is assumed to be a pair. Once you know these two options, you would choose `30kg` since it's closer to `29` than `27.5`.

In this example, I just have it calculating `27.5`, but I haven't figured out how to go back and calculate the closest possible weight once the if statement fails.

```
const BAR = 20;

const PLATES = [
  1.25,
  2.5,
  2.5,
  5,
  5,
  10,
  10,
  20,
  20,
];

const sumPlates = (plates) => {
  return plates.reduce((acc, plate) => {
    return acc + (plate * 2);
  }, 0);
};

const rack = (targetWeight) => {
  const sortedPlates = PLATES.sort((a, b) => b - a);

  const rackedPlates = sortedPlates.reduce((acc, plate) => {
    if ((BAR + (plate * 2) + sumPlates(acc)) > targetWeight) {
      // Calculate here the closest possible rack weight
      return acc;
    }

    acc.push(plate);

    return acc;
  }, []);

  return {
    targetWeight,
    barbellWeight: BAR + sumPlates(rackedPlates),
    plates: rackedPlates,
  };
};

console.log(rack(47)); // gives 45 but should give 47.5
console.log(rack(29)); // gives 27.5 but should give 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually a modified version of a [Change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem), which itself is a modified version of Knapsack problem.

Depending on the size and type of the given weight, you can use dynamic programming solution in the link to find all possible combinations, and do a `O(N)` iteration to find the closest one to the target weight.

---

However given your current implementation, I would just do the following:

```
var x = rack(targetSum);
var y = rack(2*targetSum - x);
ans = the closer one to targetSum
```

Comment: Gah, I couldn't think of the problem's name when making this question but thanks for reminding me!

Comment: No problem, though I think the second part of my answer is a better option based on what you have.